# Get indices of columns satisfying multiple conditions in new column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With the following dataframe as an example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample':['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 'Base':[2, 10, 3], 'A':[0,5,100], 'C':[0,10,7]})
```

I would like to add a new column called `df["indices"]` with the indices of columns `df["A"]` and/or `df["C"]` provided they satisfy 2 conditions:

1. Must be greater than 5
2. `df["A"]/df["Base"]` or `df["C"]/df["Base"]` must be greater than or equal to 1

The resulting dataframe would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample':['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 'Base':[2, 20, 3], 'A':[0,6,100], 'C':[0,10,7], 'indices': ['','C','A,C']})
```

I can get True or False values for my first condition with `df[['A','C']] > 5` but I cannot get it to work with my condition 2 which is based on another column in my dataframe. Getting the indices where I get True in a new column is yet another story. I imagine something with apply and get_loc or index but I cannot get it to work no matter how I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create a boolean mask satisfying the two given conditions, then use `DataFrame.dot` on this mask to get the indices:

```
m = df[['A', 'C']].gt(5) & df[['A', 'C']].div(df['Base'], axis=0).ge(1)
df['indices'] = m.dot(m.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
```

---

```
  Sample  Base    A   C indices
0      X     2    0   0        
1      Y    10    5  10       C
2      Z     3  100   7     A,C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.loc` to assign values back to the column when any number of conditions are met.  A simple approach would be to have 3 of these, each with your desired conditions.  You could also probably chain together `np.where` to achieve the same thing if you wanted.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sample':['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 
                   'Base':[2, 10, 3], 
                   'A':[0,5,100], 
                   'C':[0,10,7]})

df.loc[(df['A'] / df['Base'] >=1) & (df['C'] / df['Base'] >=1), 'indicies'] = 'A,C'
df.loc[(df['A'] / df['Base'] >=1) & (df['C'] / df['Base'] <1), 'indicies'] = 'A'
df.loc[(df['A'] / df['Base'] <1) & (df['C'] / df['Base'] >=1), 'indicies'] = 'C'
```

Output

```
   Sample   Base      A     C   indicies
0       X      2      0     0       NaN
1       Y     10      5    10         C
2       Z      3    100     7       A,C
```